# Appending list data to txt

Tags: python

My goal is to append all the values in  list "lis" to "txt",am pasting a snippet below,I always see only the last element being appended to "txt",how can i fix it?I tried to use txt += but that wont work either because I want the list data "lis" to be in-between "txt[0:tagEnd] " and "wikiText + txt[endTag:len(txt)]"

```
for i in range(len(lis)) :
    txt = txt[0:tagEnd] + lis[i] + wikiText + txt[endTag:len(txt)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do this:

```
txt = txt[:tagEnd] + ' '.join(lis) + wikiText + txt[endTag:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make a single string from the list and append that?

```
for i in range(len(lis)):
  all_strings += " " + lis[i]

txt = txt[0:tagEnd] + all_strings + wikiText + txt[endTag:len(txt)]
```